# mx recodrs misconfigured in ZPanel

Tags: dns, hosting, mx-record, zpanel

I am using ZPanel for my domain and hosting.

now my domain is working is fine. but i facing some problems on Webmail configuration.

I am updating My DNS Recods in Zpanel like this

Host Name TTL Target A Records @ 3600 A xxx.xxx.xxx.xx mail 86400 A xxx.xxx.xxx.xx ns1 172800 A xxx.xxx.xxx.xx ns2 172800 A xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

MX Records

Host Name TTL Target
@ 86400 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx @ IN xxx.xxx.xxx.xx @ IN xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

NS Records

Host Name TTL Target @ 17280 NS01.domain.com @ 17280 NS02.domain.com

I think this is all good.

But when i am sending mails the sender did not receive... and after 4hours it is come back to my mail.

When i am receiving mail from senders it is working good and i am receiving fast.

I am checking http://mxtoolbox.com/ for Errors in DNS Configuration and con't find solution.

any help is great appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary a DNS problem.
Try logging into your SSH account as root and check the mail logs.
If there's too much data, clear it, resend the mail and check again.

1) Check log:

```
cat /var/log/maillog
```

2) Clear log

```
cat /dev/null > /var/log/maillog
```

3) back to step 1).